# Ubuntu 16.04 - stop Software Update Center from interrupting nightly full-screen games?

Tags: updates, software-center, games, fullscreen

As more computer games come out with Linux support, especially those distributed through Steam, some Ubuntu behaviors that were trivial before might become more annoying.

For example, I was just on my 8th go at a boss fight, and made it to the literal final turn... when, at 3:00 a.m., the Software Update Center window popped in over my fullscreen game, locking out my keyboard controls and preventing me from dodging. Here comes fight #9...

(1) Unlike Windows, I don't see any options in the Software & Updates settings to set a *particular time of day* to check / alert about updates. Is there some more hidden preferences for that?

(2) And, there's also the strong annoyance that a fullscreen game isn't immune to routine system alert pop-ups.  Do pop-up alerts get priorities (eg info, alert, critical), and/or can we change settings to not interrupt fullscreen applications?

Thanks!